# loop through 2 dataframes

Tags: r, loops

I am new to R and trying to loop through each row of df1 and search for rows in df2 that are close in distance (5mi/8046.72m). I think df1 is looping as intended but I don't think it is going through all of df2.

```
{for (i in 1:1452){

p1 <- df1[i, 4:5]
p2 <- df2[1:11, 2:3]

d <- distCosine(p1, p2, r=6378137)

return(d< 8046.72)
i <- i+1}
}
```

I get the output:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please consider reading up on [ask] and how to produce a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: In your current code, there are some weird things going on. Where are you returning to? And why are you manually increasing i?

Answer (score 1):

I would just use an `apply` function. First, let's make your problem reproducible by creating some "fake" data - I am making the lon/lat pairs artificially close so that we can get a few `TRUE`'s back in the results:

```
library(geosphere)

df1 <- data.frame(X1 = sample(letters, 100, replace = T),
                  x2 = sample(letters, 100, replace = T),
                  x3 = sample(letters, 100, replace = T),
                  lon = sample(10:12 + rnorm(100, 0, 0.1), 100, replace = T),
                  lat = sample(10:12 + rnorm(100, 0, 0.1), replace = T))

df2 <- data.frame(x1 = sample(letters, 100, replace = T),
                  lon = sample(10:12 + rnorm(100, 0, 0.1), 100, replace = T),
                  lat = sample(10:12 + rnorm(100, 0, 0.1), 100, replace = T))
```

We can then create two matrices containing the values of interest:

```
m1 <- as.matrix(df1[, c("lon", "lat")])
m2 <- as.matrix(df2[1:11, c("lon", "lat")])
```

Now we can use the `apply` function across the rows of `m2` which return a `100 X 11` matrix:

```
results <- apply(m2, 1, FUN = function(x) distCosine(x, m1))
```

To get the less than 5 mi (~8046.72m), results, we simply subset:

```
results[results < 8046.72]

# Showing the next two for alternative output
which(results < 8046.72)
which(results < 8046.72, arr.ind = T)
```

Note: In your question, it looks like you are interested in the first 1,452 rows -- this would mean the results would we be a `1,452 X 11` matrix.

Comment: thanks, I added row names to each df, is there a way to keep these to identify which rows match based on their id?